# how to abort matlab function in runtime with code?

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab code running in a loop. The code is pretty heavy and time-consuming. Instead of using Ctrl-C, I am looking for a way to abort the function with GUI callback in runtime. I have my code designed as follows

```
function test
  figure;
  uicontrol('pos',[20 20 40 20],'string','abort','fontsize',12, 'callback', 'error(''p'');');
  k=0;
  while(k<10000)
    m=1:10000;
    x = rand(size(m));
    for t=1:10000
        x=x+sin(2*pi*m*0.02 + mod(t, 5)*pi);
    end
    % other code will be run here
    plot(m, x);
    drawnow;
    k=k+1
  end
end
```

Above code just as an example. I know it could be optimized but I don't concern about that now. I just want to know why above code doesn't work. The callback in which the 'error' function issued will not abort the code. How to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error callback is not called within the loop. Hence, the error callback and the loop are independent processes.

You could design your function this way:

```
   function test
      figure;
      AbortButton = uicontrol('Style','togglebutton','pos',[20 20 40 20],'string','abort','fontsize',12);%, 'callback', 'error(''p'');');

      k=0;
      figure;
      while(k<10000)
          val = get(AbortButton,'val');
          if (val == 0)
            m=1:10000;
            x = rand(size(m));
            for t=1:10000
                x=x+sin(2*pi*m*0.02 + mod(t, 5)*pi);
            end
            % other code will be run here
            plot(m, x);
            drawnow;
            k=k+1;
          elseif (val == 1)
              break;
          end
      end
    end
```

This is a rudimentary way, but might help.